# JSON code error 'Extra Data' when trying to dump/load a dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to load a dictionary onto a JSON file, and then later in the code search the JSON dictionary for a key to load and print the associated values.
I continue to get an error.
This is how I am dumping the data into the file

```
password_dictionary = {}
with open('dictionary.json', 'a') as f:
    dictionary = "dictionary.json"

#function to encrypt user-entered password before dumping it into a JSON file
def encrypt_and_dump(username, password):
    e_password = password.encode('utf-8')
    encrypted = k.encrypt(e_password)
    d_encrypted = encrypted.decode('utf-8')
    a = {site: [username, d_encrypted]}
    try:
        with open(dictionary, 'r') as f:
            password_dictionary = json.load(f) 
    except FileNotFoundError:
        password_dictionary = {}
    password_dictionary.update(a)
    with open(dictionary, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(password_dictionary, f)
```

and this is how I am attempting to load and search the information

```
def search_and_decrypt():
        r_site = str(input("Enter the Site Name to retrieve your credentials (Password Manager is case sensitive.): "))
        with open(dictionary, 'r') as f:
            password_dictionary = json.load(f) if f.readable() else {}
        for site, user_pass in password_dictionary.items():
            if site == r_site:
                print("ACCOUNT FOUND") 
                c_password = str(pwinput.pwinput("Confirm your Password Manager password to decrypt login credentials: "))
                if c_password == m_password:
                    decrypt_user_pass = k.decrypt(user_pass)
                    print(decrypt_user_pass)
                else:
                    print("Site Account not found.")
```

I continue to get these errors, however. I get these errors when attempting to dump the code (in the first block)

```
 File "/Users/makaylagalbraith/Documents/Python/PasswordManager.py", line 138, in <module>
    encrypt_and_dump(username2, c_password2)
  File "/Users/makaylagalbraith/Documents/Python/PasswordManager.py", line 72, in encrypt_and_dump
    password_dictionary = json.load(f) 
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the append mod 'a' when you open the json file, that mess up with your JSON file.

Just read the existing JSON file, update the dictionary with the new data, and then write the updated dictionary back to the file.

```
def encrypt_and_dump(username, password):
    e_password = password.encode('utf-8')
    encrypted = k.encrypt(e_password)
    d_encrypted = encrypted.decode('utf-8')
    a = {site: [username, d_encrypted]}

    try:
        with open(dictionary, 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        data = {}

    data.update(a)

    with open(dictionary, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
```

Also in your `search_and_decrypt()` the loop is wrong, it should be

```
for site, user_pass in password_dictionary.items():
```